# CSS Tabs remove bottom border on active tab, when having a background image

Tags: html, css, tabs

I have a tabmenu which looks like this:
[image: tab]

Currently, the borders are added on the listitems, but i want to put the bottom border on the ul, because it needs to have a full width and a little bit of margin before the first li.

Normally, a bottom border to the ul is added and a bottom border to the active li with the same backgroundcolor does the trick, but here i have a background-image and i can't figure out how to achieve the same.

Does somebody has a solution?

**Update** posted on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jpw3q/

```
<ul class="tabmenu">
    <li data-tab-contentid="general" class="active">Algemene gegevens</li>
    <li data-tab-contentid="brands">Merken</li>
    <li data-tab-contentid="openinghours">Openingsuren</li>
    <li data-tab-contentid="promotions">Promoties</li>
    <li data-tab-contentid="advertise">Mijn advertenties</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the background image does indeed complicate things a bit. you could however use the same background image on your `li` qnd position them one pixel down over the bottom border of your `ul`. The disadvantage of this technique is that you will have to position the background exactly in the `li` to align perfectly with the background image of the `ul`, which makes it hardly a dynamic solution.

I think you should keep your css as is and add the small line to the left of the first `li` and to the right of the last one, and mimic the effect this way. (At least if I understand correctly wath you are after) This should be easily achieveable with a pseudo selector like `:before` or `:after`.

I think the css would look something like this:

```
li:first-child {
  position: relative;
}
li:first-child:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Obviously you will need to change the width, and apply something similar to `li:last-child:after`, but I guess you get the general idea. If not, feel free to ask!

and your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jpw3q/4/

Comment: Thanks PeterVR, your pseudo selector solution works. Just need to fix some minor issues, but it works

Comment: graag gedaan @RubenGekiere ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using pseudo elements. It's a bit tricky but it works:

```
.tabmenu {
    position: relative; /* Needed for absolutely positioned pseudo elements */
    display: table; /* Needed to clear floats */
    padding-left: 0; /* Reset to 0 so left border doesn't get "pushed" away */
}

.tabmenu:before, .tabmenu:after {
    /* These styles set the bottom border that are "outside" of the menu */
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.tabmenu:before {
    left: -100%; /* Extend the left border beyond the its parent container */
}

.tabmenu:after {
    right: -100%; /* Extend the right border beyond the its parent container */
}
```

I've set up a jsfiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/jpw3q/7/

Answer (score 1):

Just use border none

```
ul li.active {border-bottom:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can decrease height of background image and you can give the border.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one!

```css
ul { overflow: hidden; margin-bottom: -1px; list-style: none;}
ul li { width: 100px; float: left; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px; }
ul li.active { border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Tab 1</li>
  <li class="active">Tab 2</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
</ul>
```